# Add random noise to tone using python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to detect sudden loud noises in audio recordings. One way I have found to do this is by creating a spectrogram of the audio and adding the values of each column. By graphing the sum of the values in each column, one can see a spike every time there is a sudden loud noise. The problem is that, in my use case, I need to play a beep tone (with a frequency of 2350 Hz), while the audio is being recorded. The spectrogram of the beep looks like this:

[image: Spectrogram of beep]

As you can see, at the beginning and the end of this beep (which is a simple tone with a frequency of 2350 Hz), there are other frequencies present, which I have been unsuccessful in removing. These unwanted frequencies cause a spike when summing up the columns of the spectrogram, at the beginning and at the end of the beep. I want to avoid this because I don't want my beep to be detected as a sudden loud noise. See the spectrogram below for reference:

[image: Labeled Spectrogram of recording]

Here is what the graph of the sum of each column in the spectrogram:

[image: Sum of Columns graph]

Obviously, I want to avoid having false positives in my algorithm. So I need some way of getting rid of the spikes caused by the beginning and end of the beep. One idea that I have had so far is to add random noise with a low decibel value above and/or below the 2350 Hz line in the beep spectrogram above. This would ideally, create a tone that sounds very similar to the original, but instead of creating a spike when I add up all the values in the column, it would create more of a plateau. Is this idea a feasible solution to my problem? If so, how would I go about creating a beep sound that has random noise like I described above using python? Is there another, easier solution to my problem that I am overlooking?

Currently, I am using the following code to generate my beep sound:

```
import math
import wave
import struct

audio = []
sample_rate = 44100.0

def append_sinewave(
        freq=440.0, 
        duration_milliseconds=500, 
        volume=1.0):
    """
    The sine wave generated here is the standard beep.  If you want something
    more aggresive you could try a square or saw tooth waveform.   Though there
    are some rather complicated issues with making high quality square and
    sawtooth waves... which we won't address here :) 
    """ 

    global audio # using global variables isn't cool.

    num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (sample_rate / 1000.0)

    for x in range(int(num_samples)):
        audio.append(volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * ( x / sample_rate )))

    return


def save_wav(file_name):
    # Open up a wav file
    wav_file=wave.open(file_name,"w")

    # wav params
    nchannels = 1

    sampwidth = 2

    # 44100 is the industry standard sample rate - CD quality.  If you need to
    # save on file size you can adjust it downwards. The stanard for low quality
    # is 8000 or 8kHz.
    nframes = len(audio)
    comptype = "NONE"
    compname = "not compressed"
    wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, sample_rate, nframes, comptype, compname))

    # WAV files here are using short, 16 bit, signed integers for the 
    # sample size.  So we multiply the floating point data we have by 32767, the
    # maximum value for a short integer.  NOTE: It is theortically possible to
    # use the floating point -1.0 to 1.0 data directly in a WAV file but not
    # obvious how to do that using the wave module in python.
    for sample in audio:
        wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int( sample * 32767.0 )))

    wav_file.close()

    return


append_sinewave(volume=1, freq=2350)
save_wav("output.wav")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer - more of a question.

You're asking the speaker to go from stationary to a sine wave instantaneously - that is quite hard to do (though the frequencies aren't that high). If it does manage it, then the received signal should be the convolution of the top hat and the sine wave (sort of like what you are seeing, but without having some data and knowing what you're doing for the spectrogram it's hard to tell).

In either case you could check this by smoothing the start and end of your tone. Something like this for your tone generation:

```py
tr = 0.05  # rise time, in seconds
tf = duration_milliseconds / 1000  # finish time of tone, in seconds

for x in range(int(num_samples)):
    t = x / sample_rate  # Time of sample in seconds
    
    # Calculate a bump function
    bump_function = 1
    if 0 < t < tr:  # go smoothly from 0 to 1 at the start of the tone
        tp = 1 - t / tr
        bump_function = math.e * math.exp(1/(tp**2 - 1))
    elif tf - tr < t < tf:  # go smoothly from 1 to 0 at the end of the tone
        tp = 1 + (t - tf) / tr
        bump_function = math.e * math.exp(1/(tp**2 - 1))

    audio.append(volume * bump_function * math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * t))
```

You might need to tune the rise time a bit. With this form of bump function you know that you have a full volume tone from `tr` after the start to `tr` before the end. Lots of other functions exist, but if this smooths the start/stop effects in your spectrogram then you at least know why they are there.  And prevention is generally better than trying to remove the effect in post-processing.